# Ballerina wso2/gmail package : unable to import

Tags: ballerina, wso2-bi

I want to import wso2/gmail package to my ballerina project.

```
import wso2/gmail;
```

But when I try to import the package to my , I get the following error.

```
ballerina pull wso2/gmail

your ballerina version does not support for package: wso2/gmail:*. following versions are supported: 0.9.6
```

My ballerina version is 0.981.1 However according to https://central.ballerina.io/wso2/gmail and https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/package-gmail ballerina 0.982.0 is also supported. Is there a way to import the latest wso2/gmail 0.9.7 which is compatible with ballerina 0.981.0.

p.s: My requirement is use gmail-connector and send an email notification. Feel free to suggest if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ballerina pull wso2/gmail` attempts to pull the latest package from central. `wso2/gmail` 0.9.7 version is only compatible with 0.982.0 ballerina distribution.

Since you have 0.981.0 ballerina version, you can pull 0.9.6 version using `ballerina pull wso2/gmail:0.9.6`.

Other option is to upgrade to ballerina 0.982.0 version which as of now is an RC version - https://ballerina.io/downloads/ (https://product-dist.ballerina.io/dev/0.982.0-rc1/ballerina-platform-0.982.0-rc1.zip)

You cannot use wso2/gmail 0.9.7 with ballerina 0.981.0.

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly tried to pull wso2/gmail 0.9.7 thinking that ballerina 0.981.0 is the latest. It worked when I pulled wso2/gmail 0.9.6 :)